# Bootstrap 3 navbar alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started using Bootstrap today and I'm having this alignment issue with the navbar. The links move to the next line on desktop:

[image]

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b5mbbwgb

The code:

```
 <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
           <div class = "container">
             <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-links-collapse">
                           <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
                   <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-logo-collapse">
                    <img alt="logo" width="164" height="30" src="http://placehold.it/164x30?text=LOGO">
                </a>
                <a class = "navbar-toggle pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse">

                   </a>

                </div>
                    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-header-search-collapse">
                        <form class="nav navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>

                   <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-header-links-collapse">
                          <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                  <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                                  <li><a href = "#">Social</a></li>
                                  <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>                             
                                  <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                          </ul>
                   </div>
           </div>
   </div>
```

After numerous attempts I'm not able to fix these issues:

1. Links move to the next line
2. Search input has lines on top & bottom on mobile. See screenshot below

[image]

Can someone give me a hint on what needs to be done to fix these 2 issues? I'm learning, so I'd appreciate a basic explanation too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/4v9sb1kd/)

Is this what you meant?

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-links-collapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-logo-collapse">
                <img alt="logo" width="164" height="30" src="http://placehold.it/164x30?text=LOGO">
                    </a>
                <a class = "navbar-toggle pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse">

                </a>

                </div>
            <div class = "nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-header-search-collapse">
                <form class="nav navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-header-links-collapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>                             
                        <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you look in firebug u'd see that `nav-header-search-collaps` and `nav-header-links-collapse` their divs width overlap. so this is what I changed:

```
<div class = "nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-header-search-collapse">

<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-header-links-collapse">
```

Or maybe this:

[Option2](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/vfze337g/)

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-links-collapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-logo-collapse">
                <img alt="logo" width="164" height="30" src="http://placehold.it/164x30?text=LOGO">
                    </a>
                <a class = "navbar-toggle pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse">

                </a>

                </div>
            <div class = "nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-header-search-collapse">
                <form class="nav navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-header-links-collapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Social</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>                             
                        <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yep, this exactly. But I have no clue what changes you made :D. Edit: The lines on top/bottom of the search on mobile still persists though.

Comment: @Yeti, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: It's in the original post, at the bottom.

Comment: what would you like to see instead?

Comment: I never added those, so I have no clue why they are shown in the first place. I'm learning and would like to know why they are showing up. Will remove them once I know how.

Comment: both code fixes the alignment issue. But in both of them the gap between the logo and search box has almost doubled!

Comment: That's because of the `navbar-nav` I've added to `nav-header-search-collapse`. it overrides the margin left\right of -15px and sets it to 0px.
This is something you can fix locally in case you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `pull-left` class to `#nav-header-search-collapse`, it would set a width to that div.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="nav-header-search-collapse">
```

Comment: This works but the gap between the logo and searchbox has doubled!

Answer (score 1):

This example should at least give you some thing to work with.

1) As far as the borders go, you have to remove the `box-shadow` and the `border`

2) The placement of your search bar is trickier. It's probably best to use a different class for your `navbar-toggle` so they don't conflict and the rest is really just provisioning space for it inside the `navbar`. It may be better to just create your own classes for things like this so you aren't working around or fighting with predifined rules.

See example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .search-toggle {
  right: 15px;
  top: 17.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-form {
    top: -42px;
    left: 165px;
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .search-toggle {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-form {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    margin-right: -15px;
    left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-bs"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-logo">
        <img alt="logo" width="164" height="30" src="http://placehold.it/164x30?text=LOGO">
      </a>

      <a class="search-toggle pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-search"></a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-search">
        <form class="nav navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>

              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-bs">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```